# Proving Isomorphism Linear SubSpaces

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, linear-transformations, group-isomorphism

$X$ & $Y$ are two subspaces of $W$. Show $(X+Y)/Y$ is isomorphic to $X/(X∩Y)$.

So to show that I believe I have to show a bijective homomorphism of linear spaces $ T: W\to  V$. Now there is the theorem: Two finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension.

So to find a basis for each of the vector space & count the elements, I would assume $X$ & $Y$ have $x$ & $y$ elements respectively? Then show that the two bases have the same number of elements by counting the bases of $(X+Y)/Y$ which I am a little unsure about.

Answer (score 1):

How about defining a linear map $L: X\to \frac{X+Y}{Y}$ via $L(x)=x+Y$?

Is $L$ surjective? What is the kernel of $ L$?

Comment: L is not surjective because for X+Y/Y we need to have XY-Y=X(Y-1) for L to be mapped to every element of the codomain? I am a little confused also about how this helps with the proof

Comment: Let $x+y+Y$ be an arbitrary element of $X+Y/Y$. Then $x+y+Y=x+Y$ because $x+y-x=y\in Y$. So $L(x)=x+Y=x+y+Y$ and hence $L$ is surjective. I hope you are familiar with the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: got it and yes i am so the two is isomorphic

Comment: and for the kernel mapping to the identity, is kernel of L X/(X∩)?

Comment: $\ker L $ is $X\cap Y $.

Comment: @jamesblack I'm sorry. I'm a little bit busy right now. Anyway, the keyword here is **second isomorphism theorem for vector spaces**. You can find out more details by Googling.

Comment: sorry to bother you but i did look that up and the only part i dont understand is why you chose x+y+Y as an element?how does that cover the entire space of X+Y/Y?

Comment: all the other proofs using this also used x+y+Y but i just dont understand how that covers the quotient space X+Y/Y

Comment: An arbitrary element of  $X+Y $ is of the form $x+y $ where  $x\in X $ and $y\in Y $. Then what will be an arbitrary element in the quotient?